# How to get the id's within the html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a screen scraping on twitter, i'm using Jsoup library and this is a sample of html code of the page :

```
<div class="stream permalink-stream">
  <ol id="stream-items-id" class="stream-items js-navigable-stream">
    <li id="stream-item-tweet-692459333712347137" class="js-stream-item stream-item stream-item expanding-stream-item " data-item-type="tweet" data-item-id="692459333712347137">
    <li id="stream-item-tweet-692470683348123649" class="js-stream-item stream-item stream-item expanding-stream-item " data-item-type="tweet" data-item-id="692470683348123649">
    <li id="stream-item-tweet-692489785978523648" class="js-stream-item stream-item stream-item expanding-stream-item " data-item-type="tweet" data-item-id="692489785978523648">
  </ol>
  <ol class="hidden-replies-container"></ol>
</div>
```

what I'm trying to do first is to get all id's of the li tags in the web page, to use them after in a loop to get the text inside each li tag.

the result I want, is something like :

- id1 = stream-item-tweet-692459333712347137
- id2 = stream-item-tweet-692489785978523648
- id3 = stream-item-tweet-692489785978523648

I've tried something like with Jsoup, but it doesn't work :

```
Elements scriptElements = doc.getElementsByTag("li");       

for (Element element :scriptElements ){                
                    for (DataNode node : element.dataNodes()) {
                        System.out.println(node.getWholeData());
                    }

              }
```

thanks !

Comment: You have classes to deal with: `$('.js-stream-item.stream-item')` will give you those elements!

Comment: `var array = $('#stream-items-id .stream-item[id]').map(function(){return this.id;}).get();`

Comment: I would do $("*").each(function(){ var id = $(this).attr("id"); });  Add it to array each loop.  if I understood you correctly, and just wanted to get all ids of all elements that have an id.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

       var szResult=""
        $('.stream-items').find('li').each(function () {

            szResult = szResult +"\n"+ "id" + ($(this).index() + 1) + "= " + $(this).attr('id')
                
        });

        alert(szResult)


    });

Comment: I'm using Jsoup for this, is there any equivalent for each(function ()..., thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here's an example:

```
$('ol').find('li').each(function(k,v)
{
   alert('id = ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: There could be many `ol` elements. You need to be specific..

Comment: @RayonDabre just giving him the idea..